# Установить время конца суток JS

Tags: javascript

Как определить время конца сегодняшних суток.
Если сейчас дата например:

```
var nowDate = new Date()
```

> nowDate : 2019-03-14T14:54:16.147Z

Что нужно сделать, чтобы в переменнут nextDate записать дату:

> nextDate : 2019-03-15T00:00:00.147Z

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Напишите способ в ответ, чтобы можно было лайкнуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без сохранения микросекунд (предполагаю, что в формулировке вопроса они остались по недосмотру):

```js
let nowDate = new Date();
let nextDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate() + 1, -nowDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
console.log('GMT midnight:', nextDate.toISOString())

let nextLocalDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate() + 1)
console.log('Local midnight:', nextLocalDate.toString())
```

Если нужна полночь не по Гринвичу, а по местному времени, то надо убрать четвертый параметр из `new Date()` (cм. переменную `nextLocalDate`).